# Sort JavaScriptObject in DataGrid with GWT

Tags: json, gwt

I have a list of objects retrieved as JSON String as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.1/tutorial/JSON)

In the DataGrid I do the sorting like this (I illustrate one colomn for simplicity)

```
nameColomn.setSortable(true);
    final ListHandler<SomeObject> nameColomnSortHandler = new ListHandler<SomeObject>(dataProvider.getList());
    nameColomnSortHandler.setComparator(nameColomn, new Comparator<SomeObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(SomeObject o1, SomeObject o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });
    dataGrid.addColumnSortHandler(nameColomnSortHandler);
```

And this is my object

```
public class SomeObject extends JavaScriptObject {

           //Other methods
           public final native String getName() /*-{ return this.n; }-*/;
    }
```

The sorting doesn't work. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setComparator` on a different sort handler than the one you are attaching to the `DataGrid` in your sample code.

Everything else seems OK to me.  What do you mean when you say the sorting doesn't work?  Does nothing happen?  Is there a JavaScript error?  Does the mouse cursor change when hovering over the column header?

Comment: I wish it was that :) I corrected it. The error is when adapting my code for the question

Comment: If only it were that easy :-)  What about my questions on what the failure scenario is?

Comment: Sorry ... yes the mouse cursor change when hovering. I tested with a "normal" object and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with JavaScriptObject, actually I was sorting before setting any data in the DataProvider.